# Analyzing the complexity of this sort algorithm

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting

I know merge sort is the best way to sort a list of arbitrary length, but I am wondering how to optimize my current method.

```
def sortList(l):
    '''
    Recursively sorts an arbitrary list, l, to increasing order.
    '''  
    #base case.
    if len(l) == 0 or len(l) == 1:
        return l

    oldNum = l[0]
    newL = sortList(l[1:]) #recursive call.

    #if oldNum is the smallest number, add it to the beginning.
    if oldNum <= newL[0]:
        return [oldNum] + newL

    #find where oldNum goes.
    for n in xrange(len(newL)):
        if oldNum >= newL[n]:
            try:
                if oldNum <= newL[n+1]:
                    return newL[:n+1] + [oldNum] + newL[n+1:]

            #if index n+1 is non-existant, oldNum must be the largest number.
            except IndexError:
                return newL + [oldNum]
```

What is the complexity of this function? I was thinking O(n^2) but I wasn't sure. Also, is there anyway to further optimize this procedure? (besides ditching it and going for merge sort!).

Comment: I Think This a wired _Selection Sort_ that combined with Partition of _Quick Sort_ , And I think yes it's O(n^2)!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a few places I'd optimize your code.

- You do a lot of list copies: each time you slice, you create a new copy of the list. That can be avoided by adding an index to the function declaration that indicates where in the array to start sorting from.
- You should follow PEP 8 for naming: `sort_list` rather than `sortList`.
- The code that does the insertion is a bit weird; intentionally raising an out-of-bounds index exception isn't normal programming practice. Instead, just percolate the value up the array until it's in the right place.

Applying these changes gives this code:

```
def sort_list(l, i=0):
    if i == len(l): return
    sort_list(l, i+1)
    for j in xrange(i+1, len(l)):
        if l[j-1] <= l[j]: return
        l[j-1], l[j] = l[j], l[j-1]
```

This now sorts the array in-place, so there's no return value.

Here's some simple tests:

```
cases = [
    [1, 2, 0, 3, 4, 5],
    [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    [5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 1]
]

for c in cases:
    got = c[:]
    sort_list(got)
    if sorted(c) != got:
        print "sort_list(%s) = %s, want %s" % (c, got, sorted(c))
```

The time complexity is, as you suggest, O(n^2) where n is the length of the list. My version uses O(n) additional memory, whereas yours, because of the way the list gets copied at each stage, uses O(n^2).

One more step, which further improves the memory usage is to eliminate the recursion. Here's a version that does that:

```
def sort_list(l):
    for i in xrange(len(l)-2, -1, -1):
        for j in xrange(i+1, len(l)):
            if l[j-1] <= l[j]: break
            l[j-1], l[j] = l[j], l[j-1]
```

This works just the same as the recursive version, but does it iteratively; first sorting the last two elements in the array, then the last three, then the last four, and so on until the whole array is sorted.

This still has runtime complexity O(n^2), but now uses O(1) additional memory. Also, avoiding recursion means you can sort longer lists without hitting the notoriously low recursion limit in Python. And another benefit is that this code is now O(n) in the best case (when the array is already sorted).

Answer (score 0):

A young Euler came up with a formula that seems appropriate here. The story goes that in grade school his teacher was very tired and to keep the class busy for a while they were told to add up all the numbers zero to one hundred. Young Euler came back with this:

[image: (n^2+n)/2]

This is applicable here because your run-time is going to be proportional to the sum of all the numbers up to the length of your list because in the worst case your function will be sorting an already sorted list and will go through the entire length newL each time to find the position of the next element at the end of the list.